# How to set up Bitbucket in PhpStorm 2019

Tags: wordpress, git, phpstorm, bitbucket

The terms Git, repository, commit and push are completely new to me but I want to set up a version control system for my WordPress website.

I use PhpStorm and want to use Bitbucket - how would I do this?

(I've spent the afternoon answering the above question so will share below)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Step 1:** Install Bitbucket Linky using this [guide](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000152210-PHP-storm-with-bit-bucket). Note [Bitbucket Connector](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector) is no longer being developed.

**Step 2:** Set up a new private repository on Bitbucket. If you're using Wordpress, I'd recommend creating a repository for each plugin you are developing, rather than for the entire install. Leave it empty for now.

**Step 3** Create a new project in PHPStorm or use an existing one. Click VCS>Create Git Repository. Select the path of your project.

**Step 4** Now the repository is properly set up, I then added - using Finder - all of my files into the local repository folder.

**Step 5** Select all of your project - which should be in red text - and click VCS>Git>Add. This will have added these files to the project, but not yet pushed them to the remote server.

**Step 6** Now select the root directory of your project and click VCS>Git>Commit Directory.

**Step 7** Go to VCS>Git>Remotes and add a new remote. You need to get this in Bitbucket by clicking 'I will be starting from scratch' and then copying the URL (https://youraccount@bitbucket.org/youraccount/yourrepo.git) and pasting it into PHPStorm.

**Step 8** Click VCS>Git>Push. This actually moves the files to the server.

Hope that helps some one - took me ages to figure out. You're now in the capable hands of many guides on how to use Git.